# Erro na configuração de MapRoute

Tags: dicionário, route, nullable

O seguinte erro é retornado pra mim:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'numerodeserie' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Equipamento(System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'SCO.Controllers.EquipamentosController'

A configuração do meu MapRoute, faço dessa maneira:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "EquipamentosTrafego",
 url: "Equipamentos/{cidadecod}/{contratocod}/Trafego/{filtro}",
 defaults: new
 {
    controller = "Equipamentos",
    action = "EquipamentosTrafego"
 }
 );
```

E na minha View tento acessar dessa maneira:

```
<td align="center">
<div class="list-group-item">
     <a href="/Equipamentos/@item.cidadecod/@item.contratocod/Trafego/OFF">
           <span class="badge" style="font-size: 18px; background-color:@item.totaleqpson_stts">@item.totaleqpson</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

O que está errado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Eu tinha um outro MapRoute configurado que estava sendo referenciado. Coloquei esse MapRoute depois do novo MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "EquipamentosTrafego",
       url: "Equipamentos/{cidadecod}/{contratocod}/Trafego/{filtro}",
       defaults: new
       {
           controller = "Equipamentos",
           action = "EquipamentosTrafego"
       }
       );
```

**MapRoute que dava conflito, colocado depois:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Equipamento",
      url: "Equipamentos/{cidadecod}/{contratocod}/{numerodeserie}/{faixa}",
      defaults: new
      {
          controller = "Equipamentos",
          action = "Equipamento"
      }
      );
```